# Hat for shutting down the Pi with a button

Tags: hat

Are there any Raspberry Pi hats which allow to shut down the Pi by pressing a button ?

Are there any DIY open hardware projects which describe step-by-step how to build such a hat ?

Comment: You only need a switch and 2 wires. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42945/8697 for my solution

Comment: This functionality is available in the kernel. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.txt and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-poweroff.txt

Answer (score 1):

No, but there are open *software* options, such as [Adafruit's GPIO-Halt](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GPIO-Halt) which'll do what you ask, with a default pin of #21, which is the last pin on J8. You change the pin in the .c file, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

This 'Pi Supply Switch – On/Off Power Switch for Raspberry Pi' might be of interest to you:
[Pi Supply Switch](https://www.pi-supply.com/product/pi-supply-raspberry-pi-power-switch/)

Answer (score 0):

I use a Button that flips in 2 ways. One for sending a signal to a GPIO Pin to shut it down via software. And the other to the RUN pin to start it back up again.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still interested in this question, this might be worth noting as a prepackaged solution: [Pimoroni: OnOff SHIM](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/onoff-shim).