# Shutdown Button for Raspberry pi

Tags: hardware

I am using the RP3 as a NAS (OpenMediaVault installation) and would like a button that I can hold down to trigger a controlled shutdown. I had a NAS that I could shut down like that, but miss this simple and yet important feature on the Pi.

Sure I can log in and shut it down, but I do not want to be an admin just because I want to turn the box off sometime and simply pulling the cable is not what anybody should do to a Linux system...

Any ideas? Is there a simple out of the box idea?

Thanks!

Comment: A simpler solution (only requires a button no resistors and doesn't waste resources polling) http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42945/8697 (still a duplicate)