# my program wont work when I auto run it

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, boot, hardware

I have a program that turns my pi on and off at a push of a button. The program works and i know that it runs on boot because it prints text and I can see it in the terminal. But what happens is when i press the button, nothing happens. I have tried 2 different ways of auto running the program.

my code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def shutdown(channel):
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

    GPIO.add_event_detect(3, GPIO.FALLING, callback = shutdown, bouncetime = 2000)
```

and i have tried to auto run it by putting "python powerbutton.py" at the bottom of the file /etc/rc.local and .bashrc

Comment: How have you tried to auto run it? What does the code look like? Where is it printing text to? Is the process still running after boot?

Comment: Hey all, please keep in mind how [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) are to be used...

Comment: i have added my code and how i auto ran it

Comment: `.bashrc` is not the place to put the command. When you put it *at the bottom of rc.local* did you put it ABOVE any lines that say `exit 0` - also, when using `rc.local` you *wont* need sudo in your script - `rc.local`  is executed as root

Comment: I'm sure someone else will be kind enough to point out the error in your code.  Of course there may well be errors in your wiring as well.  As to the code error I suggest a Python tutorial is the best start point.

Comment: I'm assuming this is python3 Try putting the line: #!/usr/env python3 at the very top of your script.  Also, show us what you put into the rc.local file.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete, but from the look of your (apparently) incomplete program it is not running.

For a working solution see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42945/8697

This would also be more robust, and less prone to unwanted shutdown due to spikes.