# How to put Raspberry Pi into shutdown by keypress/hold?

Tags: python, bash

I am running latest retropie on a rpi3b+. I am also using retrogame to map GPIO pins the keyboard keys to arcade buttons.

What I would like to do is run the `sudo shutdown` command if a designated key (or designated combo of keys) was held down for 5 seconds.

I’m not super versed in bash so am having trouble getting started.  I’ve tried searching under the assumption that maybe this has been done before but couldn’t find anything. I know python but think it may be too much run simultaneously with retropie.

I appreciate any help or links in the right direction.

Comment: *"I know python but think it may be too much run simultaneously with retropie."* -> A background process that is just waiting for an event like this should use pretty much zero CPU resources no matter how it's done.  Shouldn't use more than a smidge of RAM either, although I think the variation-based-on-method will be a bit broader.

Comment: I used to run a Shutdown Daemon (started with crontab) to shutdown on button press (although this is no longer necessary) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42945/8697 You may be able to adopt this technique using different activation criteria.

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyboard macro tool, AutoKey that can do what you want.

*AutoKey is a Linux Utility for Text Substitution , Hotkeys and Desktop Automation.*

https://autokey.github.io/intro.html